# showTextEvery: 1 not working on Google chart for Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-visualization

I need all the hAxis labels to be shown.
The full code is more than 4000 lines of code so I will paste what I think is the only important part of the code:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation');
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
  if(i%10==0)
  {
      data.addRow(['' + i / 10 + '', elevations[i].elevation]);
  }
  else
  {
      data.addRow([null, elevations[i].elevation]);
  }
}
document.getElementById('chart_div').style.display = 'block';
chart.draw(data, {
  height: 250,
  colors: ['#F00'],
  legend: 'none',
  titleY: 'Elevation (m)',
  titleX: 'Distance',
  hAxis: {
      slantedTextAngle: 90,
      showTextEvery: 1,
  }
});
```

This is the current result:
[image]

And I need the Distance of the hAxis to show 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7... in a correct font-size and angle.

Note: I'm printing empty title name everywhere except multiples of 10, so if there's a way of NOT adding that title to that column that will also work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying both ColumnChart and Bar from Google chart's options, I saw it wasn't working on all case scenarios and this is what I think worked best:

For loading the API:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
```

For Creating the LineCHart:

```
chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
```

And then for the options later in the code:

```
var options = {
  legend: { position: "none" },
  height: 250,
  colors: ['#F00'],
  hAxis: {
      title: 'Distance (<%= Event.DistanceUnits %>)',
      showTextEvery: 10
  },
  vAxis: {
      title: 'Altitude(m)'
  }
};
```

And of course on the results I was showing all of them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    data.addRow(['' + i / 10 + '', Math.round(elevations[i].elevation)]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically all you have to do is to set `hAxis.showTextEvery` to `10`

To omit the values of the first column from the tooltips use a tooltip-column.

When you set the `hAxis.slantedTextAngle`-option also set the `hAxis.slantedText`-option to `true`

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {
  //some dummy-data
  var elevations = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 300; ++i) {
    elevations.push({
      elevation: 100 * Math.random()
    })
  }
  var results = elevations;
  //dummy-data end
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Sample');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation');
  data.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    role: 'tooltip'
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    data.addRow([String(i / 10),
      elevations[i].elevation,
      String(elevations[i].elevation)
    ]);
  }
  document.getElementById('chart_div').style.display = 'block';
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {

    colors: ['#F00'],
    legend: 'none',
    height: 250,
    titleY: 'Elevation (m)',
    titleX: 'Distance',
    hAxis: {
      slantedTextAngle: 90,
      slantedText: true,
      showTextEvery: 10,
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```